# Prefixer mixin for adding vendor prefixes to CSS properties

Tags: css, sass, include, scss-mixins, scss-lint

why the Webkit and Moz  not including in output in css file ?

the scss mixin

```
@mixin prefixer($property, $value, $prefixes: ()) {
  @each $prefix in $prefixes {
    #{"-" + $prefix + "-" + $property}: $value;
  }
  #{$property}: $value;
}
```

including

```
*{
   @include prefixer(box-sizing,border-box,("webkit","moz","o","ms"));
}
```

css output

```
* {
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information on your project, I will make a guess. You most probably have [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) running with the tool you're using to compile your SCSS.

> [Autoprefixer is a] plugin to parse CSS and add vendor prefixes to CSS rules using values from [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/).

It uses the [Browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) you have configured to add or remove the vendor prefixes to the rules.

Your mixin is not necessary.